# Signing Windows 8 app using Visual Studio Cordova tools with custom certificate

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Signing Windows 8 app using Visual Studio Cordova tools with custom certificate.

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your custom certificate under `res/cert/windows8/` in **VS2013 CPT3** and `res/native/windows/` in **VS2015 Preview** and then build the project or create app package. Visual Studio will create package with custom certificate.

Certificate file name = CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx

Comment: Try CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx